# Как можно реализовать отправку формы подтверждения админу

Tags: python, django, rest

Если у меня есть модели юзеров. И изначально при регестрации юзер является DefaulUser - как можно осуществить такой функционал при котором пользователь для того что бы стать ContentMaker отправляет сначало запрос админу в виде формы где он заполняет поля о себе и т.д. после заполнения эта форма отправляется к админу предположим ввиде той же формы которую пользователь заполнил и только после подтверждения админа, пользователь становится из DefaultUser - ContentMaker имея права создавать и редактировать (аудиозаписи). Я использую Rest API заранее спасибо. Ниже я привел свою модель юзеров

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
username = models.CharField('username', max_length=55, null=False)
email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True, null=False)

is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

is_Seller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_Contentmaker = models.BooleanField(default=False)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

objects = CustomUserManager()

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.email}'


class DefaultUser(MyUser):
    avatar_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', default='default-avatar.jpg', 
null=True)


class ContentMaker(MyUser):
    about = models.TextField()
    reason_to_become_contentmaker = models.TextField()
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.about}'
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.